# Getting destination directories/ locations of spark jobs executed by all users

Tags: apache-spark

I am working on a reporting tool and I need to find out the output locations of saved RDDs of spark jobs executed by all users on the cluster. I tried the spark history server API/ spark event log/ spark listener/ YARN log but could not get the location of the executed jobs there.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Please update with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. If your code is writing to file isn't it obvious that you already know the output location? I think you are missing about executors/part files.

Comment: For example a simple word count program where a file is read and after needed transformations, the final RDD is written to the disk having words and their counts. It is not about my program but in general we need to find out the output directories of different jobs being executed on the cluster, i.e. YARN cluster .

Comment: You're using YARN so assuming you are writing to HDFS.  If so, you specify the path, don't you?  If you're writing to the local file system and specify an absolute path, that's where it will be on each executor. If a relative path IIRC it is relative to the spark bin directory? If you are collecting your data back to the driver your data will be written as per previous comments, but this time on the machine hosting the driver.

Answer (score 0):

the final output goes under the path you pass to {{write(path: String)}} called on your HadoopRDD or dataframe.

Comment: That's true. But this is not my question. My question is to determine destination locations of all the executed jobs without the knowledge of their implementation. Like, from event log or some other place, I can get to know to what location the RDD was written. I am not able to find that from event log or spark history server rest API.  This is for reporting purpose only.